# Who should go first? Static variable issue

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm creating a game for a university assignment and one of the criteria is that the program asks who goes first.

I'm having a little trouble with this as I have defined `ComputerPlayer firstPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer secondPlayer` initially as `null`, to then set the value based on a button press, but I keep getting an error as the players are already previously defined.

Can anyone help me in re-wording this so it works? Thanks.

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("Human");
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Computer");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Who Goes First?"));
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        ComputerPlayer firstPlayer = null;
        ComputerPlayer secondPlayer = null;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);


        if(button1.isSelected()) {       
            ComputerPlayer firstPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
            ComputerPlayer secondPlayer = new AIPlayer();
        }

        if(button2.isSelected()) {       
            ComputerPlayer firstPlayer = new AIPlayer();
            ComputerPlayer secondPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
        }

        GameLogic logic = new GameLogic();

        logic.addPlayer(firstPlayer); 
        logic.addPlayer(secondPlayer); 

        logic.startGame();
    }
```

Comment: "I keep getting error" -> could you be more specific about that?

Comment: The variables `ComputerPlayer firstPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer secondPlayer` are already defined in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete "ComputerPlayer" in if blocks. You already create this object, so u don't need do it again.

```
if(button1.isSelected()) {       
    firstPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
    secondPlayer = new AIPlayer();
}

if(button2.isSelected()) {       
    firstPlayer = new AIPlayer();
    secondPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
}
```

Comment: create, yes, it's declaring

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(button1.isSelected()) {       
        ComputerPlayer firstPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
        ComputerPlayer secondPlayer = new AIPlayer();
    }

    if(button2.isSelected()) {       
        ComputerPlayer firstPlayer = new AIPlayer();
        ComputerPlayer secondPlayer = new HumanPlayer();
    }
```

You're assigning values to these local variables that are not used. No matter what you want to do these methods are wrong.